# Does every Lebesgue measurable set $A$ with $m(A)>0$ contain at least an open subset?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Does every Lebesgue measurable set $A$ with $m(A)>0$ contain at least a non-empty open subset?

I came across this question when I was reading the Stein and Shakarchi's Real Analysis book. Is that true? If yes, how can we prove that, otherwise, what is the counter example?

I was thinking of solving it as follows:

Since set $A$ is measurable , for any $\epsilon$ we should be able to find $F_{\epsilon} \subset A$ that $m(A - F)<\epsilon$. If we remove the boundary points of $F_{\epsilon}$, we obtain an open set. Is that valid?

Comment: It's a strange statement, since every set, measurable or not, contains the empty set, and @DavidMitra states.  However, if you remove this trivial example, the statement is not true, as there are plenty of measurable sets which do not contain a non-empty open set.

Comment: What about a set that's all boundary?; e.g. the Cantor set.

Comment: Once the question is repaired to avoid trivialities, it will probably be something like "Does every Lebesgue measurable set of positive measure have a nonempty open subset?" The answer is no; the set of irrational numbers is a counterexample.

Comment: @DavidMitra  I edited the problem statement to remove the trivialities.

Answer (score 2):

In your second-to-last sentence, "If we remove the boundary points of $F_\epsilon$, we obtain an open set", you need a further assumption: that removing the boundary points of $F_\epsilon$ doesn't change its measure. Unfortunately, this is completely false: there are nowhere dense (so every point is a boundary point) closed sets with positive measure. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set.